# Moving the text of a UILabel in a UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

How do I move the text of a UILabel from side to side and repeat itself. The UILabel is inside a UIToolbar that is an "inputAccessoryView" of the toolbar. another question that I also have is how to have multiple items as the self of something. Look in my code and you will see that I have "cell1Field1Dismiss" as the self of the input inputAccessoryView.

For further clarification I have a viewController with about 10 UITextFields and another 10 UITextFields to resign the first responder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 23)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    label.text = @"24 Hour time format only!";
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIBarButtonItem *text2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];

    //UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    //UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:text2, nil];
    [numberToolbar sizeToFit];
    self.cell1Field1Dismiss.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}
```

The the IBAction to resign the first responder is:

```
- (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)Sender
{
    [cell1Field1Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell1Field1 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell1Field2Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell1Field2 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell2Field1Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell2Field1 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell2Field2Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell2Field2 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell3Field1Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell3Field1 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell3Field2Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell3Field2 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell4Field1Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell4Field1 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell4Field2Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell4Field2 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell5Field1Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell5Field1 resignFirstResponder];

    [cell5Field2Dismiss resignFirstResponder];
    [cell5Field2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Go to this image to see the view controller mentioned.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVVpi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Resigning the KeyBoard you can use

```
[self.view endEditing:YES]  remove all the resignFirstResponders.
```

find the solution for Marquee label [here](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel)

Comment: For my project I am not using ARC and I read that your Marquee Label does. Will it still work?

Comment: @user3121577  It's ok that you can disable ARC for a specific file using a -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for that file.

Comment: how can I do that. Sorry for all the troubles but I am a newbie.

Comment: could i just use Quartz Core instead of using and importing the Marquee Label?

Comment: The Marquee Label isn't working inside the inputAccessoryView.